# Rails Error Running Gem Install PG

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am trying to push my app to Heroku and I configured my gemfile as such:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'puma'
end
```

And I am getting this error in my console when running bundle install:

```
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Then when I run gem install pg -v '0.18.4', I get the following:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

When I run `sudo gem install pg -v '0.18.4'`

I get the following:

```
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/ext
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160125-5501-ugsd1s.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

***UPDATE***

I reinstalled RVM and rails and now when I run gem install pg -v '0.18.4', it runs successfully:

```
Successfully installed pg-0.18.4
Parsing documentation for pg-0.18.4
Done installing documentation for pg after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
```

But when run bundle install, I get this:

```
Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/benwong/Desktop/ruby/rails_projects/blog2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/ext
/Users/benwong/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160126-44660-1ufenyc.rb extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config
sh: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
sh: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQconnectionUsedPassword()... yes
checking for PQisthreadsafe()... yes
checking for PQprepare()... yes
checking for PQexecParams()... yes
checking for PQescapeString()... yes
checking for PQescapeStringConn()... yes
checking for PQescapeLiteral()... yes
checking for PQescapeIdentifier()... yes
checking for PQgetCancel()... yes
checking for lo_create()... yes
checking for pg_encoding_to_char()... yes
checking for pg_char_to_encoding()... yes
checking for PQsetClientEncoding()... yes
checking for PQlibVersion()... yes
checking for PQping()... yes
checking for PQsetSingleRowMode()... yes
checking for PQconninfo()... yes
checking for rb_encdb_alias()... yes
checking for rb_enc_alias()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... yes
checking for rb_w32_wrap_io_handle()... no
checking for rb_str_modify_expand()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for PGRES_COPY_BOTH in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for PGRES_SINGLE_TUPLE in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for PG_DIAG_TABLE_NAME in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for struct pgNotify.extra in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for ruby/st.h... yes
checking for C99 variable length arrays... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/benwong/Desktop/ruby/rails_projects/blog2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/pg-0.18.4/mkmf.log

current directory: /Users/benwong/Desktop/ruby/rails_projects/blog2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/benwong/Desktop/ruby/rails_projects/blog2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling gvl_wrappers.c
compiling pg.c
compiling pg_binary_decoder.c
compiling pg_binary_encoder.c
compiling pg_coder.c
compiling pg_connection.c
pg_connection.c:2394:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'gettimeofday' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                gettimeofday(&currtime, NULL);
                ^
1 warning generated.
compiling pg_copy_coder.c
compiling pg_errors.c
compiling pg_result.c
compiling pg_text_decoder.c
compiling pg_text_encoder.c
compiling pg_type_map.c
compiling pg_type_map_all_strings.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_class.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_column.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_mri_type.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_oid.c
compiling pg_type_map_in_ruby.c
compiling util.c
linking shared-object pg_ext.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/haven/.sm/pkg/active/lib'
ld: file not found: dynamic_lookup
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [pg_ext.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/benwong/Desktop/ruby/rails_projects/blog2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/p

g-0.18.4 for inspection.
    Results logged to /Users/benwong/Desktop/ruby/rails_projects/blog2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/pg-0.18.4/gem_make.out

Using puma 2.15.3
Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.4
Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.4
Using sass 3.4.21
Using tilt 2.0.2
Using spring 1.6.2
Using rdoc 4.2.1
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.7.2
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using warden 1.2.4
Using mail 2.6.3
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using uglifier 2.7.2
Using sprockets 3.5.2
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Is the same *pg_config* used when running as regular user and as root?

Comment: Sorry. I'm not understanding. I tried again with sudo gem install with-pg-config and I get the following: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have PostgreSQL installed to install pg gem. Also PATHs will need to be configured.
You can use http://postgresapp.com/ to easily install PostgreSQL on Mac. And use this to configure PATH: http://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html

Comment: I installed PostgreSQL and configured the PATH, but still gives me: ( An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling ) when I do bundle install.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for me it must Have all psql dependency so it will work

```
sudo apt-get install -y libpq-dev build-essential postgresql-server-dev-all libpgsql-ruby postgresql ruby-dev && gem install pg
```